# Android - Eclipse setup missing Google APIs

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I just finished setting up my Eclipse with the Android plug-in.
(i.e https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

Now when I do the following
1. Eclipse > Preferences > Android, I see a lot of "Target Name" like Android 1.1 - Android 2.1

However, in the book that I'm reading, I'm also supposed to see a "Target Name" called "Google APIs".
I don't see that.

What am I missing? Is that a separate install?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to install the Google APIs packages.

Open the Android SDK and AVD Manager (the plugin should've added an icon, otherwise you can find it in the menus - on Windows it's under Window).  Then go to "Available Packages", refresh, and find the Google APIs to download.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue by updating my ADT as my previous one did not include the Google APIs.

[ADT UPDATE LOCATION AND INFORMATION](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)